# How do I return the previous Sunday from 7 days ago using PHP date()?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Here is what I have so far:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('-7 days')); 
$start = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($date,'previous Sunday'));
```

When outputting $start, it returns: 1969-12-31 06:00:00

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$date` needs to e a timestamp

```
$date = strtotime('-7 days'); 
$start = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('previous Sunday',$date));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the arguments the wrong way round:

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('previous Sunday', $date));
```

---

**Edit**: Furthermore, you have made `$date` a formatted string. It needs to be a timestamp, so your code should look something like this:

```
$date = strtotime('-7 days'); 
$start = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('previous Sunday', $date));
```

Comment: It returns: 1969-12-28 12:00:00 with it flipped around.

Comment: `$date` should be a timestamp (eg. `time()`), not a formatted date. Here's an example: http://ideone.com/3eUkA

Comment: Or you can go the way of cryptic code with `$start = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('previous Sunday', time() - 604800));` :)

Comment: @Mchl Yes, you could. I generally prefer to let PHP work these things out for me, unless I have enough to be a genuine performance hit.

Comment: That was only a joke. Noone should really do this. ;) At the very least make it 7 * 24 * 3600.

Comment: @Mchl I'm quite relieved you just said that.

Answer (score 0):

Per [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('last Sunday', $date));
```

Comment: Not exactly what the question is about. Today it will return `2011-01-16 12:00:00` while I think mike wants `2011-01-09 12:00:00`

Comment: Isn't "last" defined in relation to the date given by `$date`?

Comment: Ah yes... somehow I missed that there is `$date` there. :P Still.. `last` and `previous` work the same, and the real issue was in `$date` being a formatted date instead of a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If your date is not a timestamp you can still use `strtotime`, like suppose your date was passed in already and is in a string format of another kind.

```
$date = '2013-11-10';
$lastsunday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date.' last Sunday'));
```

This can save a bit of time trying to get your date into a format that "works"